# Cannot uninstall half installed mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mongodb-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-server' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to install the ppa version (old docs) and now I think I have two versions with circular dependencies that can never be removed.

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; so please provide, and have you tried what it suggested - ie. `apt --fix-broken` or `apt -f install` ?  Providing your PPA would also be helpful; as issue relates to *unstated* release & *unstated* PPA/source you've added but given no details of.

Answer (score 1):

I use using zsh and the `mongo*` wasn't working when purging. Switching to bash worked.